# Error while creating new database record in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to asp.net mvc. However, this is what I've done:

In the controller,

```
          public ActionResult Create()
    {


        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Customerservice/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="CustomerServiceMappingID")] Maping serviceToCreate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View(); 

          var dc = new ServicesDataContext();

          dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);
          dc.SubmitChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

The View goes like this:

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(new List<object> 
                                         {new {value="Active" , text="Active"},
                                        new {value="Pending", text="Pending" },
                                         new {value="Disabled", text="Disabled"}}, "value", "text", Model.Status))
```

There are 4 fields. However, when I try to use Status , I get an exception saying " Object Reference not set to an instance of object"

Answer (score 0):

In the GET action you need to pass the model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // the model could also be fetched from the DB given
    // an unique ID passed as argument to this action
    var model = new Maping();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @Nishanth, are you getting the same exception after this change? On the same line as before? I very much doubt this. You are most probably having some other issue.

Comment: @Nishanth, is the view strongly typed to `Maping`? Also what is the type of the `Status` property on your model?